# How to separate the pages in webView?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiwebview

I downloaded [this](http://zaldzbugz.posterous.com/how-to-search-a-string-inside-uiwebview) example `UIWebView`to open files.

I'm using it to open an .rtf file, but it shows the file as one long page and this is not my target. I want to show pages in the .rtf file and be able to search through them.

Are there are any solutions to this problem?

Comment: is there are any extensions except pfd is paged format??

Comment: I suppose any word-processing document (Word, Pages, LibreOffice) would be, but I doubt UIWebView can open those.